# Is it possible to make VBA Macro function on the level of file?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering something.

I have one VBA Macro Excel code that checks  Unique Citizenship Number and returns is it correct or not.

But to start it I have to call Macro when I start Excel, to press ALT+F11, than F5 and than to enter code, to compile it and after that my function Check_JMBG(adr) is entered in the Excel functions and I can call it in the Excel worksheet.

But when I start some other Excel files I have again to create Macro for that purpose.

Now I was wondering an example can I make and how can I make that my function is immediately present there when I start some other Excel files and to call it immediately like it is built-in  ?

Example to call function: Check_JMBG(A1), in A1 is entered filled as text: 2003969265121

Below is code to check Unique Citizenship Number:

```
' Function for checking JMBG validation
Function Check_JMBG(JMBG As String) As String
    If (Len(JMBG) <> 13) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERROR: Length of JMBG is not 13!"
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERROR: JMBG contains non-numerical characters"
    ElseIf Not fctBlnCheckDate(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERROR: Wrong date entered!"
    ElseIf fctBlnCheckSum(JMBG) Then
        Check_JMBG = "ERROR: Wrong checksum!"
    Else
        Check_JMBG = "JMBG is correct"
    End If
End Function
' Function to check JMBG day, month, year validation
Private Function fctBlnCheckDate(JMBG As String) As Boolean
    Dim intDay As Integer, intMonth As Integer, intYear As Integer
    Dim datCheck As Date

    intDay = Int(Left(JMBG, 2))
    intMonth = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 3, 2))
    intYear = Int(Mid$(JMBG, 5, 3)) + 1000

    datCheck = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay)

    fctBlnCheckDate = _
        (Year(datCheck) = intYear) And _
        (Month(datCheck) = intMonth) And _
        (Day(datCheck) = intDay)

End Function
' Function to check JMBG control number and control sum
Private Function fctBlnCheckSum(JMBG As String) As Boolean
    Dim intCheckSum As Integer, i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 13
        intCheckSum = intCheckSum + Int(Mid$(JMBG, i, 1)) * (IIf(i < 7, 8, 14) - i)
    Next
    fctBlnCheckSum = (intCheckSum Mod 11) <> 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You need to make an Add-In.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151490

Comment: please also refer to http://ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm or http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm